# Python syntax error when subsetting a dataset?

Tags: python

I'm getting to grips with python and was wondering why my code isn't outputting correctly. For example, when I run this, it correctly subsets the data:

```
data_2 = data[(data.region == 1)]
```

The correct data is also subsetted when I run this:

```
data_2 = data[(data.localarea == 1)]
```

But when I try to put them together as an 'or' statement, it's not correctly subsetting the data:

```
data_2 = data[(data.region == 1) | (data.localarea == 1)]
```

If I remove the brackets before and after the | then python gives me an error message.

I can get this working in SPSS as:

```
Select if (region=1 or localarea=1).
```

I'm keen to move to python so I would be grateful for any advice.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `data_2 = data[(data.region == 1) or (data.localarea == 1)]`. The pipe (`|`) is a bitwise operator in python. See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/bitwise_operators_example.htm

Comment: What is `data`? Is it a list, dictionary, Pandas series, Numpy array, etc.?

Comment: Is this using Pandas? If so, then please include that information. It's good to include as much information about your context as possible

Comment: Ahh yes, using pandas. Apologies, I'm new to python. Thanks!